# get style.css into to content using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to get `style.css` into received content.

```
 preg_match("/<link rel='stylesheet'.*href='(.*?style\.css.*?)'.*\>/i",$src,$matches);
```

Above code is working fine. But I need more clear filter like below
if style is name like below then avoid to fetch css.

```
push_ucid_bar_style.css
```

And just get only `style.css`
So what should i do change in my code.

Comment: Can you add bit more code and explain bit properly about what you want to achieve. Its bit unclear of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you just want to match `style.css` you could remove the wildcard matches `preg_match("/<link rel='stylesheet'.*href='(style\.css)'.*\>/i",$src,$matches);`

Comment: @Subash i need only style.css in received content. but do not need any style like this 'push_ucid_bar_style.css'..

Comment: sorry @Subash when i remove wildcard matches then i can not get any style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet'.*href='(.*?(?<!push_ucid_bar_)style\.css.*?)'.*\>
```

Explanation:

I have just put a negative look behind in your regex. When you find style.css it will only match if it is not preceded by `push_ucid_bar_`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/7/)

```
    $re = '/<link rel=\'stylesheet\'.*href=\'(.*?(?<!push_ucid_bar_)style\.css.*?)\'.*\>/i';
    $str = '<link rel=\'stylesheet\' bla bla bla href=\'1style.css\'bla bla bla \\>
    <link rel=\'stylesheet\' bla bla bla href=\'2style.css\'bla bla bla \\>
    <link rel=\'stylesheet\' bla bla bla href=\'push_ucid_bar_style.css\'bla bla bla \\>
    <link rel=\'stylesheet\' bla bla bla href=\'3style.css\'bla bla bla \\>
    <link rel=\'stylesheet\' bla bla bla href=\'4style.css\'bla bla bla \\>';
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++)
       echo $matches[$i][1]."\n";
```

Update:

If you have just few names to be ignore then you put `|` (OR) condition in the negative look behind described above...

But if there is a long list of names to be ignored then you first get names with your original regex and loop over the ignoreList of names to check if that matches. If that matches then you should ignore it.

For the second option you can try this:

[Second Option](http://ideone.com/UNweeD)

Comment: Thanks for answer. yes it's fix my issue but not everytime push_ucid_bar_ is exist so something different exist.

Comment: Then you need a list , to avoid please provide that

Comment: Thanks brother, i will try

Comment: watch out the link at the end of the answer

Answer (score 0):

example_string = `<link rel='stylesheet' href='push_ucid_bar_style.css' \>`
you need to more filter using **$matches[1]** which returns you 'push_ucid_bar_style.css'
you can now put another check by http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php or you can write http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php or 
you can use  http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chudasamachirag, i will try to your suggestoin.